# Excel VBA: Copying certain noncontiguous cells from a worksheet row into a row of another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet where each row (except the header) represents a single entry, each column a field (pretty standard stuff). The fields go up to column BB.

I want to copy certain entries (those matching a particular value for a particular identifying field) onto another sheet. However, I don't want all the fields that are on the original sheet, only about 10, which aren't contiguous on the original sheet.

Therefore, for each (valid) row, I would want to do something like this:

```
for each origRow in origSheet.Rows
    if strcomp(origRow.cells(idCellNumber).value, myId, vbTextCompare) = 0 then
        copySheet.Row(copySheetRowNumber).value = origRow.Range(Cells(1), Cells(8), Cells(15), Cells(4))
        copySheetRowNumber++
    end if
next
```

Obviously this code is invalid. Furthermore, I can't simply copy the entries as a whole and then delete the irrelevant columns, since the sheet contains existing data which would be deleted. Can anyone suggest the fastest way to accomplish this?

Comment: The problem described in http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/292030-copy-cell-workbook-paste-another-workbooks-cell.html seems to be quite close to your needs.

Comment: By bonCodigo: Can you please copy an screen of your datasheet if what you need is different from Juri Ruut's answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim arrSourceCols, arrDestCols
Dim x As Long

arrSourceCols = Array(1, 3, 5, 7)
arrDestCols = Array(2, 4, 8, 12)

For Each origRow In origSheet.UsedRange.Rows
    If StrComp(origRow.Cells(idCellNumber).Value, myId, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

        For x = LBound(arrSourceCols) To UBound(arrSourceCols)
            copySheet.Cells(copySheetRowNumber, arrDestCols(x)).Value = _
                                  origRow.EntireRow.Cells(arrSourceCols(x)).Value
        Next x

        copySheetRowNumber = copySheetRowNumber + 1
    End If
Next
```